# Drawing a filled arc of an ellipse -- not aligning the ellipses

Tags: tikz-pgf, ellipse

I am trying to follow the guidance from this answer to a previous question:

[How to draw a ellipse sector from focus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635389/how-to-draw-a-ellipse-sector-from-focus)

In my own code I have written:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[variable=\t, domain=0:360] plot ({8*(cos(\t))}, {4*sin(\t)});
        \fill ({8*cos(30)},{4*sin(30}) circle (.05);
        \fill ({8*cos(60)},{4*sin(60}) circle (.05);

        \fill ({-sqrt(12)},0) -- ({8*cos(30)},{4*sin(30)}) arc[start angle = 30, end angle = 60, x radius = 4, y radius = 2] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The perimeter of the ellipse isn't lining up with filled sector, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I suspect that I'm not sure how `arc` works out the center of the ellipse, but I thought that I was basically doing whatever that answer is doing.  It's also possible that I'm misunderstanding or miscalculating some of the relevant geometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last line must be:

```
\fill ({-sqrt(12)},0) -- ({8*cos(30)},{4*sin(30)}) arc[start angle = 30, end angle = 60, x radius = 8, y radius = 4];
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ah right, I was stupidly dividing the radius by half.

Answer (score 3):

While [Raffaele Santoro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/689534/16595) found the actual problem, TikZ can draw ellipses and has polar coordinates that can be used with two different radii:

```
\draw circle [x radius=8, y radius=4];
\draw ellipse[x radius=8, y radius=4];

\draw ({-sqrt(12)},0) -- (30:8 and 4)
      arc[start angle=30, end angle=60, x radius=8, y radius=4] -- cycle;
```

(There is no difference between the path operations `circle` and `ellipse`, it just comes down to the values of `x radius` and `y radius`.)

The key system also allows you to specify both *x* and *y* radius for a whole scope and it will be used for all circles, ellipses and arcs unless they're specified again:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x radius=8, y radius=4]
\draw circle[];
\fill[radius=1pt] (30:8 and 4) coordinate (30) circle []
                  (60:8 and 4)                 circle [];
\fill ({-sqrt(12)},0) -- (30) arc[start angle = 30, end angle = 60] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

But this still needs you to specify the radii more than once for the polar coordinates.

You can use, of course, always TeX macros, say `\newcommand*\radiusX{8}`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x radius=\xRadius, y radius=\yRadius]
\newcommand*\xRadius{8}
\newcommand*\yRadius{4}
\draw circle[];
\fill[radius=1pt] (30:{\xRadius} and \yRadius) coordinate (30) circle []
                  (60:{\xRadius} and \yRadius)                 circle [];
\fill ({-sqrt(12)},0) -- (30) arc[start angle = 30, end angle = 60] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Or special PGFMath functions that access those values (of course, this could also just be TeX macros again):

```
\pgfset{declare function={xR=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius}; 
                          yR=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius};}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x radius=8, y radius=4]
\draw circle[];
\fill (30:xR and yR) coordinate (30) circle [radius=1pt]
      (60:xR and yR)                 circle [radius=1pt];
\fill ({-sqrt(12)},0) -- (30) arc[start angle = 30, end angle = 60] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Or you just declare your own PGFMath functions which is the most convenient way to me:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=8; b=4;}, x radius=a, y radius=b]
\draw circle[];
\fill[radius=1pt] (30:a and b) coordinate (30) circle []
                  (60:a and b)                 circle [];
\fill ({-sqrt(12)},0) -- (30) arc[start angle = 30, end angle = 60] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `plot` needs bigger number of `sample` to get a smoother curve. Below is a simple way using avaiable smooth curves `ellipse` and `arc`. To get a point on an ellipse, we take polar coordinates, for instance,

```
(30:a and b)
```

where `30` is the angle, `a` and `b` are the major and minor semi-axes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=4;b=2;}]
\fill[cyan,opacity=.5] (0,0)--(30:a and b) arc(30:60:a and b)--cycle; 
\draw (0,0) ellipse(a and b);
\draw[fill=white] (30:a and b) circle(1pt) (60:a and b) circle(1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```